# Node/ Javascript - Combining PDFs and creating Bookmark style / Table of Contents like Acrobat does

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, npm

I am currently using the following:

```
const pdfmerger = require('pdfmerger')
var pdfStream = pdfmerger(array_of_pdf_paths)
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(final_pdf_path)
pdfStream.pipe(writeStream)
pdfmerger(array_of_pdf_paths, final_pdf_path)
```

What I need is to automatically generate inside the final pdf a Table of Content tree (or Bookmarks) which has entries in the TOC to easily jump to each pdf file.
Since it's a combine of 50 pdf documents. Any ideas?

See below an example of Bookmarks in Acrobat

[image]

Comment: ----

I've tried to install node-pdfbox, I'm hitting an error on: > node-gyp rebuild

      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/java.o
      In file included from ../src/java.cpp:1:
      ../src/java.h:7:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
      #include <jni.h>
      
     gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
     gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
     gyp ERR! not ok 
     npm WARN api@1.0.0 No description
     npm WARN api@1.0.0 No repository field.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `node-pdfbox`? It is a bridge to PDFBox that allows full PDF manipulation: https://pdfbox.apache.org/

From what I've seen going through their java examples - you should be able to set bookmarks in the final PDF file *after* you have added your PDFs by going through the array and getting page counts and PDF filenames.

Comment: I'll check it right now. Indeed their java api has a CreateBookmark sample. I'll see if it's implemented in the node-pdfbox version. https://memorynotfound.com/apache-pdfbox-bookmark-pdf-example/#creating-bookmarks

Comment: I've tried to install node-pdfbox, I'm hitting an error on: > node-gyp rebuild CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/java.o In file included from ../src/java.cpp:1: ../src/java.h:7:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found